# Entity Framework Core2 LINQ - each join runs as a separate query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have something like this in my C# MVC controller:

```
from table1 in db.Table1.AsQueryable()
join table2 in db.Table2.AsQueryable() on table1.Col1 equals table2.Col1
join table3 in db.table3.AsQueryable() on new { table2.Col2, table2.Col5 } equals new { table3.Col2, table3.Col5 }
.
.
few more joins
.
.
WHERE ......
select new {table1.Prop1, table2.Prop2, table3.Prop3}
```

When I watch what it runs on SQL profiler, I was expecting a single query with all the joins. What it does instead, it selects all columns from all tables in separate queries. i.e. Runs

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 --Instead of * it has all column names
```

when that's finished running, it runs

```
SELECT * FROM Table3 --Instead of * it has all column names
```

and so on for each table. Tables are big so it takes too long, using a lot of memory. I added `AsQueryable()` on the entities but it didn't make a difference, still multiple queries. `db` is a `DbContext`, using core 2.

How can I change the LINQ or some other setting so the whole thing runs as a single query?

**Update**

It looks like the problem was caused by having `Convert.ToInt32(` on one of the join columns. The `int` column I was joining on is nullable in one table and non-nullable in the other table, I had `Convert.ToInt32(` on the nullable 
table, removing the convert generated a single query.

Comment: Well, you definitely don't need those `AsQueryable` calls.  Why are you doing this `...on new{ table2.Col2, table2.Col2 } equals new { table3.Col2, table3.Col2 }`?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I was trying to see if they would make a difference, they didn't.

Comment: @BradleyUffner See the edit, mistyped the same column name twice.

Comment: Are all of your other (not shown) joins sql objects?  You aren't joining in anything from a local `IEnumerable` are you?

Comment: @BradleyUffner All SQL objects, no `IEnumerable`. Also I noticed, `SELECT * FROM Table2` is not entirely correct, it does `SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM table2 INNER JOIN Table1 On Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1` and then it runs a `SELECT * FROM Table1`, then runs the join between Table1 and Table3, etc, too many queries instead of a single query.

Comment: Hmm, I'm really not seeing any issues with your code that would cause that.  One last grasp...  Are all of the properties accessed in the query made up of simple expressions?  None of them are code based properties that execute application-side logic?

Comment: Can you simplify your query, just for debugging purposes?  Try removing everything except one or two joins, then adding in more tables until you find something that causes it to spew queries.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I tried that and introducing the 3rd table causes queries to be separated out. Join between first two tables runs a single query, but when I add the 3rd join, it first runs a query using the join between the first two tables. Then runs another query `select * from Table3`

Comment: Just for fun, try doing a "normal", single key, join between those tables, even though it's wrong.  I'm curious to see if is the multi-key join, or if there is something else odd about that table.

Comment: @BradleyUffner It seems the problem was what you hinted at above, one of the Columns I was joining table2 and table3 on was `int` in one table and `int?` in the other table. On the join I had `.. equals new { ID = Convert.ToInt32(table2.ID)}`. Removing the convert now generates a single query. With 3 tables only, I need to go through the rest of the joins as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to LINQ2SQL documents:

When you query for an object, you actually retrieve only the object you requested. The related objects are not automatically fetched at the same time.

The DataLoadOptions class provides two methods to achieve immediate loading of specified related data. The LoadWith method allows for immediate loading of data related to the main target. The AssociateWith method allows for filtering related objects.

This is an issue with Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading.

This is a great post with very good explanation.

[Lazy Loading And Eager Loading In LINQ To SQL](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/lazy-loading-and-eager-loading-in-linq-to-sql/)

Comment: Well, you're not *wrong*, but I don't think that has anything to do with this problem.